# Wordpress Slow query killing server. How to find origin?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, fastcgi

My Wordpress installation is down because of a slow query that's taking a long long time to complete. So spawing a lot of php-fpm processes and eventually, taking up all CPU.

The query is

```sql
SELECT post_id, meta_key, meta_value 
FROM wp_postmeta 
WHERE post_id IN (95,150,155,160,165,181,183,186, ...goes on to total post count) 
ORDER BY meta_id ASC;
```

If you see it's trying to get post meta for all the posts published. That's a HUGE query. I'm unable to find out from where it is running.

This is causing php-fpm processes to wait for it and spawn a lot of childs consuming 100% CPU

```
[19-May-2016 03:28:47] WARNING: [pool www] child 1397, script '/var/www/index.php' (request: "GET /index.php") execution timed out (225.592993 sec), terminating
[19-May-2016 03:28:47] WARNING: [pool www] child 514, script '/var/www/index.php' (request: "GET /index.php") execution timed out (211.881885 sec), terminating
[19-May-2016 03:28:47] WARNING: [pool www] child 315, script '/var/www/index.php' (request: "GET /index.php") execution timed out (208.906923 sec), terminating
[19-May-2016 03:28:47] WARNING: [pool www] child 32244, script '/var/www/index.php' (request: "GET /index.php") execution timed out (187.837381 sec), terminating
[19-May-2016 03:28:47] WARNING: [pool www] child 30977, script '/var/www/index.php' (request: "GET /index.php") execution timed out (214.641630 sec), terminating
[19-May-2016 03:28:47] WARNING: [pool www] child 30339, script '/var/www/index.php' (request: "GET /index.php") execution timed out (195.576432 sec), terminating
[19-May-2016 03:28:49] WARNING: [pool www] child 32244 exited on signal 15 (SIGTERM) after 1498.089029 seconds from start
[19-May-2016 03:28:49] NOTICE: [pool www] child 2584 started
[19-May-2016 03:28:49] WARNING: [pool www] child 30977 exited on signal 15 (SIGTERM) after 2098.495078 seconds from start
[19-May-2016 03:28:49] NOTICE: [pool www] child 2585 started
[19-May-2016 03:28:49] WARNING: [pool www] child 315 exited on signal 15 (SIGTERM) after 1200.897107 seconds from start
[19-May-2016 03:28:49] NOTICE: [pool www] child 2586 started
[19-May-2016 03:28:49] WARNING: [pool www] child 514 exited on signal 15 (SIGTERM) after 1079.468196 seconds from start
[19-May-2016 03:28:49] NOTICE: [pool www] child 2587 started
[19-May-2016 03:28:49] WARNING: [pool www] child 1397 exited on signal 15 (SIGTERM) after 660.145154 seconds from start
[19-May-2016 03:28:49] NOTICE: [pool www] child 2588 started
[19-May-2016 03:28:50] WARNING: [pool www] child 30339 exited on signal 15 (SIGTERM) after 2401.324683 seconds from start
```

Can anyone help find me the root of this. Please help.

Comment: -silently wonders why the hell that isn't a join...- on the practical advice side, have you tried disabling all your plugins, see if it still happens? then re-enable them one by one.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the WordPress database structure, but can't you use a simple join here? Or reverse the condition: where the id is not in the list of unpublished posts.

Comment: @MichaelDibbets tried looking up for this query by grep "postmeta" on my plugin folder. There's none that looks like this one. And i've just 9 plugins that includes Yoast, W3TC, Wordpress Importer etc. All reputed. Any other way to check because it's a prod server, so can't disable all plugins.

Comment: @jeroen the problem is I'm not using the query. So I'm trying to find where the heck is it coming from. :(

Comment: wordpress uses a query builder. and postmeta is the metadata for plugins that is saved if it's not big(like integers etc...) so it can be compiled into a json. You'll never find it that way. wordpress only saves in external tables/store if  the data a plugin tries to save passes a certain treshold.

Comment: @MichaelDibbets kindly suggest a way to check. Apart from deactivating the plugins. Is there a way. Else I'll have to deactivate plugins on prod. :(

Comment: From what I remember, WordPress actually executes a db query at only 2 places, depending on whether you use mysql or mysqli so perhaps now it is only 1 place. So you should log the query and stack trace there.

Comment: @jeroen I'm logging the slow query. But trying to find out how to enable stack trace. Let me check.

Comment: I would first do what @MichaelDibbets says. Disabling the plugins one by one and see if the problems persists. That way you can rule out some options.

Comment: You could try http://php.net/manual/en/function.debug-backtrace.php

Comment: #clonedatabase #copywordpress #change wp-config.php database, #runcopyofwordpress....

Comment: Some plugin is causing this issue. As your website is down, you can rename the WordPress plugin folder ( /wp-content/plugins ) to something else for a while to get the site up. 
Create an empty plugins folder there and move plugins one by one to find out which plugin is causing this issue. It happened with me once with a plugin named "groups"

Comment: Let me disable all plugins and check one by one. My only question is, do I need to restart php5-fpm and nginx as I do this after disabling all plugins? And do I repeat restart after every plugin enable?

Comment: I've disabled all plugins, but the issue still persists. I can still see this query in slow query log. Any help?

Comment: I'll just leave this here: https://wordpress.org/plugins/query-monitor/

Comment: @dingo_d I've used the query monitor. It shows random slow queries and the one we're chasing is shown to be called by Wordpress core. update_meta_cache()
 wp-includes/meta.php:826.

Comment: When you change the theme to default one (Twenty sixteen), does the same thing happens? If yes, then try reinstalling the wordpress (just redownload and then overwrite the `wp-includes` and `wp-admin` folders). If this fails, then I'd search the database for anything odd looking. Or your server has some caching settings that are messing things up

Comment: @dingo_d Thanks for the help. I think I might have found a solution. I've activated APC and sql_nocache on mysql. And enabled Page, DB and Object Cache at W3TC. Now the CPU spikes are gone. Processlist shows less queries and I'm just monitoring now. Let's hope for the best.

Comment: Great news. Once you are sure that you've found the solution, post it below as an answer